# How to prevent access to a function in a dll in C++

Tags: c++, methods, dll, private

I am working on a game that splits its code into several .dll files. There is a method in one of these dlls that is annotated with `__forceinline` and someone accesses this method from the outside, which is not intended and I want to prohibit them from accessing it. Making this method `private` didn't yield any results, nor did removing the `__forceinline`. I assume that they call the method via its address, but I cannot be sure.

Therefore, how can I guarantee that it won't be called from the outside?

Comment: Why don't you simply NOT use `__declspec(dllexport)`?

Comment: I did not use `__declspec(dllexport)`

Comment: Then users of the DLL can't call the function in the DLL. That's how DLLs work.

Comment: @user253751 Technically, users of the DLL can call ANY function inside the DLL, they just need the memory address of the function, and then they can call it directly, since the DLL is loaded in the caller's address space. Omitting the function from the DLL's exports table just makes it *harder* to find a function's address, but it does not eliminate the possibility completely. There are other way to find function addresses (debug info, etc)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well, if we're talking about malicious host processes, the host process could also just include its own copy of the exact same code.

Comment: @user253751 I have temporarily replaced the function with a `define`, which works but is a really ugly solution. However their bot now stopped working, so I am sure they didn't just replicate the code, but where in fact calling it.

Comment: @Tare you know they can also edit your DLL, by the way, right?

Comment: @user253751 in theory I know they could replace the dll (or probably edit it in some obscure low level way). But that is about as far as my knowledge about that goes. At the very least I want to make it harder to write a bot to exploit something. The fact that the `define` solution works for now suggests, that (at least for the time being) they don't edit the dll